# inkscape arrow pokes shape

Tags: inkscape

I am drawing a block diagram. I need an arrow pointing to a rectangle. However, the arrow poke the rectangle even though end point is snapped to path.

What I need is the arrow to just touch the border.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the tips of arrows (the `Markers`) are not actually part of the curve or line but rather an overlay whose properties are a pain to change (there are several issues with the functionality of arrows, such as assigning colours and resizing though there are workarounds).

A possible solution is to transform the arrow to a path (`Path > Stroke to Path)` which gives you more freedom in resizing, snapping etc. However you loose the possibility to easily change arrow tips (e.g. of multiple lines at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to enable "snap to edges of a bounding box" The arrow still goes slightly beyond the bounding box (don't ask), but it is good enough for most arrow purposes.